# Gocardless not executing the programe after webhook parsing

Tags: php, laravel-5.7, gocardless

I'm implementing gocardless api in my website. I'm stuck in webhook. When i'm sending an webhook from sandbox test environment into my website, it showing 200 response, but after that no code is executing. and also i'm not seeing anything in response body, its showing null.

I'm using laravel 5.7 for that. Here is my code

route.php
Route::post('/webhook', 'HomeController@webhook');

HomeController.php

```
public function webhook() 
{
    $webhook_endpoint_secret = env("GOCARDLESS_WEBHOOK_ENDPOINT_SECRET");
    $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $headers = getallheaders();
    $signature_header = $headers["Webhook-Signature"];

    try {
        $events = Webhook::parse($request_body, $signature_header, $webhook_endpoint_secret);

        foreach ($events as $event) {
            print("Processing event " . $event->id . "\n");

            switch ($event->resource_type) {
                case "mandates":
                    $this->process_mandate_event($event);
                    break;
                default:
                    print("Don't know how to process an event with resource_type " . $event->resource_type . "\n");
                    break;
            }
        }

        header("HTTP/1.1 204 OK");
    } catch(InvalidSignatureException $e) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 498 Invalid Token");
    }
}


public function process_mandate_event($event)
{
    switch ($event->action) {
        case "cancelled":
            print("Mandate " . $event->links["mandate"] . " has been cancelled!\n");
            break;
        default:
            print("Don't know how to process a mandate " . $event->action . " event\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

I tried to execute some database query, nothing is working anyway. Can anyone point me out what and where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $responseBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

if ($responseBody <> "") {
    $response_new = json_decode($responseBody, true);
    foreach ($response_new["events"] as $event) {
        print_r($event); // you will see all the data which you want
        //if($event['resource_type'] == 'subscriptions')
        //payments,mandates or etc...
        //
        }
}
```

use email sending the code to debugging, when webhook called, email sends to your address with response body then you will data in the email body.
Hope you understand

Comment: I'm following official documentation. The way you approaching is outdated, can you take a look at the documentation? here is the link...
https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/api/staying-up-to-date-with-webhooks/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle the webhooks with Laravel and it's structure is to add a Middleware to verify the webhook signature:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $signature = $request->header('Webhook-Signature');

        if (!$signature) {
            throw WebhookFailed::missingSignature();
        }

        if (!$this->isValid($signature, $request->getContent(), $request->route('configKey'))) {
            throw WebhookFailed::invalidSignature($signature);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

The `isValid` method will check the signature of the webhook and your saved secret.

Then at your controller, you can handle the events that come from the webhook (remember that Gocardless can send more than one event in a single webhook request).

```php
public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $payload = $request->input();

        foreach ($payload['events'] as $event) {
            // Do whatever do you need with the events.
            }
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'ok']);
    }
```

We have created a package for Laravel can help you with the handling and processing of the Gocardless webhooks.

[Nestednet/Gocardless-laravel](https://github.com/Nestednet/gocardless-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. I was having the problem while getting the headers values. In laravel you can't get header value using `$headers = getallheaders();` You need to use `use Request;` and then `Request::header("Webhook-Signature");` which then solved my problem.